# displaying stock ticker values in sharepoint 2010 site of Content editor webpart using javascript or jquery

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, content-editor-web-part

I need to display the stockticker values as mentioned below in the home page of the SharePoint 2010 site. How can this be done?

For eg:

> MSFT 36.03, -0.775

Thanks

Comment: Isn't this question too generic? This can be done in many different ways. What is your goal exactly? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: when i open the sharepoint sites, it should automatically populated the stock values(SYMBol, rate, decrease) as shown in the example for MSFT.

Comment: how are you getting these stock values you want to show? You didn't explain if there's a web service you're calling or what else.

Comment: I dont know how to call to get stock values. My question how can i get the stock values in the sharepoint site of content editor webpart

Comment: This has nothing to do with SharePoint then! Find a website offering stock quotes with a public rest APIs or webservice, then get back to us :)

Comment: i just want it to pull from yahoo finance how's that possible